# Event call with JQuery doesn't work with ajax-generated code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a HTML select, and I call the change event using JQuery:

`$("select#id_sel").change(myMethod);`

I added an alert in `myMethod` so I can test if it's working.

When I enter the page and change the option, the alert pops up. But if by some reason (called radio button) the code of the select gets changed by AJAX, the pop up doesn't work anymore (so the event call is not working).

I've used firebug to see if the `select` id has changed after the "AJAX refresh", but it was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, you are dynamically changing the `id="id_sel"` element on the page. That means that the event handler you are connecting *once at page load* is being thrown away when the element is replaced. It does not matter that the id has not changed as that id was only used to select the element at page load time. The actual DOM element is not the same one (even if the id is the same).

If that is the case you need to use a *delegated* event handler instead:

```
$(document).on('change', '#id_sel', myMethod);
```

This works by listening for the change event to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor, *then* applying a jQuery filter, *then* applying the function to *any elements that caused the event*.

`document` is the default if you do not have a *non-changing ancestor* closer to the changing element. Do not use `'body'` as the default as it has problems with certain event types.

Note: As ids are unique and in a fast loopkup , you do not need to slow it down by prefixing the id selector with `select`.